# python: prevent creating empty files

Tags: python, file

For a bulk task I create a couple of instances of the `ProgressLog` object which will each create an empty log-file no matter if there actually will be any errors. what is the best way to prevent this?

```
class ProgressLog(object):
    """Write a message to log + progress indicator.

    """
    total = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        source_path, file_name = os.path.split(name)
        self.name = file_name
        self.source_path = source_path
        self.log_dir_name = r'log'
        self.make_log_dir(self.source_path, self.log_dir_name)
        self.reset()
        log_file = self._logfilename()
        try:
            self.f = open(log_file, 'w')
            print('\n***logging errors to {0}***\n'.format(log_file))
        except IOError, err:
            msg = 'Cannot open logfile {0}. Traceback is: {1}'.format(
                log_file, err)
            raise msg

    def _logfilename(self):
        ## hms_ddmmyyyy format
        log_name = r'{1}_{0}{2}_errors.csv'.format(
                                  time.strftime("%I%M%S"),
                                  time.strftime("%d%m%Y"),
                                  self.name)
        return os.path.join(self.source_path, self.log_dir_name, log_name)
```

Comment: Why are you creating the logfile yourself and not let python handle it? https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: The code base is written by someone else...

Comment: As for as I understand this should be expected `open(log_file, 'w')` creates a file if none exists. What exactly are you trying to do? When are you expecting an exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "magical" way to do it, you simply need to refactor the code to open the log file only on first actual call to log.

To achieve this, extract the part of `__init__` that opens the log file into a separate `_open_log` method. In `__init__` initialize `self.f` to `None`. Then, your actual logging method can begin with:

```
if self.f is None:
    self._open_log()
```

Comment: explained another way: open the output (log) file only when/if there is data to be written.

Comment: @Skaperen Thanks, I've now amended the answer to start off with an abstract similar to yours.